# Flutter > Unselect a RadioButton in a View.builder

Tags: flutter, if-statement, radio-button, unselect, gridview.builder

I am not finding any answer for my question so I am hoping to find someone who can help.

I have a GridView with text buttons.
I can select the buttons, however I **can't** **unselect** any of them.

this is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onLongPress: () => showDialog<String>(
      ),
      style: ButtonStyle(
          side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide(
              width: 5,
              color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white)),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(widget.pickerColor),
          elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(10)),
      onPressed: () {
        widget.selectedCard(widget.index); //This selects the cards, how to unselect (if Statements?)
      },
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        child: Text(
          widget.cardTitle,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17,
            color: useWhiteForeground(widget.pickerColor)
                ? const Color(0xffffffff)
                : const Color(0xff000000),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Grid

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyCardData>(
      builder: (context, cardData, child) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: GridView.builder(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final card = cardData.cards[index];
              return MyCard(
                selectedCard,
                index: index,
                isSelected: _selectedCard == index,
                cardTitle: card.name,
                pickerColor: card.cardColor,
                deleteCallback: () {
                  cardData.deleteCallback(card);
                },
              );
            },
            itemCount: cardData.cardCount,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
              maxCrossAxisExtent: 150,
              childAspectRatio: 2.5 / 1,
              crossAxisSpacing: 0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

feel free to use my git to see the full code

[get from version control](https://github.com/panval/cards.git)

Comment: are you try to make a multiselection or 1 btn selection (when others button selected, the others automatically unselected) ?

Comment: The other buttons already unselect automatically when other buttons are clicked.
I want to be able to unselect the button when i click on it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select and Unselect (other) Buttons when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74001860/select-and-unselect-other-buttons-when-clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you want to make a single selection, it will need a simple workaround.

```
int _selectedCard = -1;
selectedCard(index) {
   // this condition is when user press the same button
   // set the _selectedCard back into -1
   if (_selectedCard == index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedCard = -1;
    });
  } else{
    setState(() {
      _selectedCard = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i was just playing with if statements right at _selectedCard but I did not know how to implement them. Thank you so much, AGAIN!